# WinForms moving object C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to move an object on WinForms (with WASD) and it goes pretty well,but when I add a button at the Form, the object doesn't move anymore.

Comment: And what is your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Controls like `Button` take focus and "eat" the keypress events. A form will always set focus to one of its child controls if there is one that allows getting focus.

Set [`KeyPreview = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your form to receive these events regardless.